# Impala where clouse with bigInt

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala

we have a hive table that has a column in a bigInt type, so I tried to use a simple select query with use **where** clouse to that column.

> Impala

```
select * form table where id =  1081145387194379590;
```

but it returns 0 results.

then I tried as below way

```
select * from dmi.ti_fact_cem_detail_ufdr_other_d
where id = CAST(1081145387194379590 AS BIGINT);
```

so still I'm getting 0 results.

also my table contain few rows with id = 0;

when I tried below query

```
select * from dmi.ti_fact_cem_detail_ufdr_other_d
where id = 0;
```

it returns correct results.

> finally I tried the all above queries with Hive

and it returns correct results.

is there anything I missed here

Comment: Can you check data type in impala and hive ? Are they same BIGINT ?  if yes, try to invalidate metadata mytable to see if it works.

Comment: both are the same and I have invalidated and metatadate also updated

Comment: i dont know whats wrong with your system, i have inserted the data and tried to access, its working and giving me correct result.